# DIV command makes my program hang. How to avoid it? (Short code included.)

Tags: assembly, x86, division, freeze

(Processor Intel x86)

```
.MODEL SMALL

Print   EQU 2
Exit    EQU 4Ch

.DATA ;------------------------------------------------------

a   DW  8
b   DW  2

.CODE ;------------------------------------------------------

Start   PROC

    mov ax, SEG DGROUP
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, a
    ;div    b <---- uncommenting it makes program hang

    mov dx, ax
    add dx, '0'

    mov ah, Print      
    int 21h
    mov ah, Exit
    int 21h

; -----------------------------------------------------------

Start   ENDP
    .STACK 512

    END Start
```

If compiled with Turbo Assembler, the code outputs 8.
If i uncomment the DIV command, the code hangs.

Looking at the registers with Turbo Debugger, I saw that the DIV command sends the result of division into the AX register -- the same register which stored the number 8 and which will be sent to DX to be printed.

What did cause in DIV to hang my program? Did I oversee DIV putting data into registers which were to be used by some important background functions or... something?

Comment: `div word` divides the 32 bit quantity `dx:ax`, so you should zero `dx` otherwise you may get an overflow and a runtime error.

Comment: dziadek, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Jose
I use tasm. For the future, when I ask people for advice, is more detailed info about the compiler or the processor required? Is "Intel x86" and "tasm" sufficient?

Comment: The more info the better the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mov ax, a
;div    b
```

Since *b* is a word sized variable the `div b` instruction divides DX:AX by the word *b*. You forgot to setup DX with a zero! The division overflows and an exception was triggered.

```
mov ax, a
xor dx, dx
div b
```

Comment: What does the colon in the DX:AX register mean? And how is DX:AX register to be treated in calculations? From what you're saying, I understand DX:AX is equal to AX if DX is equal zero, right?

Comment: The colon is just an agreed syntax to express that DX contains the top 16 bits of an 32 bit quantity. (AX holds the bottom 16 bits)